# Get the outgoing URL and stop the redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect

I would like to detect when an outgoing URL matches a specific URL pattern and then stop the redirect from happening and instead alert the URL that it was trying to redirect to.

For example, if I click a tweet button on my website that sends a request to twitter.com. I would like to capture the click of the button but I don't want to actually capture the click itself, instead I want to detect the redirect attempt and alert the URL.

Is something like this possible in Javascript purely? Or a mix of server-side client-side methods?

Comment: You can listen for this event with javascripts `onbeforeunload`. However it is not possible to get the next URL as this is a very sensitive information.